# Is it possible to use the MATCH and PERCENTILE functions together in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: excel table example]

I am wondering if it would be possible to find where the 85th percentile falls using a FUNCTION like match. In this screenshot the 85th percentile would be at 61. Using MATCH I could find what position the 85th is in to then use if statements to print out where it corresponds to, in this case 61. If there is an easier way to do this without using MATCH please let me know!

edit: the 85th should be found using observations on the far right column. for this example there is 100 observations so the 85th would be 15 observations from the top.

Comment: Why is the 85 percentile also not 60, 57, 53, 46, 41, 40, 39 since they all have equal value of 3?  How are your sorting your tied values?

Comment: you may want to look at the `RANK`, or `RANK.EQ` function.

Comment: @ForwardEd essentially I want to know the number of the far left that 85% of the observations are under. If you add up the right column from the top down with 100 observations the point where the total is at 15 would be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well interesting question. On the face of it you would have to have the individual data points which I assume are (starting from bottom) 39,39,39,40,40,40,41,41,41 etc (or does the position of letter C in the row have some significance)? However you can work out that for 100 points and p of 0.85 it will be near (not exactly on) the 15th data point from the top so I think it is do-able. If you have Excel 365, try =PERCENTILE(SEQUENCE(100),0.85) and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should come with a bit of a health warning - there are 9 ways of calculating a percentile listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) and two different ways in excel - [percentile.exc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/percentile-exc-function-bbaa7204-e9e1-4010-85bf-c31dc5dce4ba) and [percentile.inc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/percentile-inc-function-680f9539-45eb-410b-9a5e-c1355e5fe2ed), neither of which give an exact answer when applied to the 85th percentile of 100 points! Percentile is the same as Percentile.inc.

However let's put this on one side for now and just go with intuition that for

```
N=100 (the number of points)

P=.15 (the fraction required)
```

we want to count the first 15 points.

The simplest way to find the corresponding value of your index row is to add a helper column containing the running total of the counts and use index/match to  find the matching row for a total count of 15. We should probably consider two cases

(1) The counts match exactly

(2) They don't match exactly so we have to take the next lowest and add one.

The formulas are in G2 (to get NP):

```
=(1-F2/100)*SUM(C2:C30)
```

In H2:

```
=INDEX(A2:A30,IFERROR(MATCH(G2,D2:D30,0),MATCH(G2,D2:D30,1)+1))
```

[image]

Really this answer is just a starting point because (a) there is a lot more that could be said about the way that the percentile should be estimated and what to do when it works out to be between two points, and (b) the formulas could be more sophisticated - in Excel 365 it could be done fairly easily with a single formula.

*Edit 1*

I have added the formulas for percentile.exc (N+1)P and percentile.inc (N-1)P+1 in G3 and G4 for comparison. In this case all three formulas give the same end result (percentiles are between 14 and 17 so will map to 61). Just to clarify, I'm not actually using percentile.exc or percentile.inc because they would require the raw data. I only need N and P to get an estimate of the percentile expressed as a position within the data (e.g. 15.15 means that it lies somewhere between the 15th and 16th data points counting from the top of the diagram).

Percentile.exc

```
=(1-F$2/100)*(SUM(C$2:C$30)+1)
```

Percentile.inc

```
=(1-F$2/100)*(SUM(C$2:C$30)-1)+1
```

[image]

*Edit 2*

A single-cell formula for Excel 365 for NP would be:

```
=LET(pcreq,F2,
counts,C2:C30,
index,A2:A30,
pos,(1-pcreq/100)*SUM(counts),
rtot,SCAN(0, counts, LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
IFERROR(XLOOKUP(pos,rtot,index,,0),XLOOKUP(pos,rtot,index,,-1))-1
```

)